# How to make a HSM key "PRIVATE" after enabling its "EXPORT" attribute using SO user?

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm

As you may know, [Thales has introduced two attributes named CKA_EXPORT and CKA_EXPORTABLE](https://thalesdocs.com/gphsm/ptk/5.9/docs/Content/PTK-C_Program/Best_Practice/key_mgmt.htm) to make the key backup procedures more secure.

Based on the documentation, only Security Officer (SO) can enable CKA_EXPORT attribute of a key and as far as I know, SO have access to non-Private keys only.

So to enable CKA_EXPORT of a key, I think I need to do the following procedure:

1. Login as "User" and create a key with PRIVATE attribute equal to False
2. Login as "SO" and modify the attributes to make EXPORT = True and Private = True.

Well, I can enable EXPORT attribute, but when I want to modify PRIVATE attribute, I receive an error which say:

```
C:\Users\admin>ctkmu m -s1 -n "myKeyName" -aP
ProtectToolkit C Key Management Utility 5.2.0
Copyright (c) Safenet, Inc. 2009-2016

Enter user PIN for slot 1:

ctkmu: Modify operation failed 0x10 - attribute read only
```

The question is: How can I make the key PRIVATE after enabling its EXPORT attribute?